# Python and multiprocessing example

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am totaly new in multiprocessing. I am trying to change my code in order to run part of it simultaneously.

I have a huge list where I have to call an API for each node. Since, the APIs are independence, I don't need the result of the first one in order to proceed to the second one. So, I have this code:

```
def xmlpart1(id):
    ..call the api..
    ..retrieve the xml..
    ..find the part of xml I want..
    return xml_part1

def xmlpart2(id):
    ..call the api..
    ..retrieve the xml..
    ..find the part of xml I want..
    return xml_part2

def main(index):
    mylist = [[..,..],[..,..],[..,..],[..,...]] # A huge list of lists with ids I need for calling the APIs
    myL= mylist[index] c
    mydic = {}
    for i in myL: 
       flag1 = xmlpart1(i)
       flag2 = xmlpart2(i)
       mydic[flag1] = flag2

   root = "myfilename %s.json" %(str(index))

   with open(root, "wb") as f:
        json.dump(mydic,f)

from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__=='__main__':
    Pool().map(main, [0,1,2,3])
```

After a few suggestions from here and from the chat, I end up with this code. The problem is still there. I run the script at 9:50. At 10:25 the first file "myfilename 0.json" appeared in my folder. Now it is 11:25 and neither of the other files have been appeared. The sublists have equal length and they do the same thing, so they need approximately the same time.

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking for help with here. The code as posted won't work, as the names code[1-4] are reused (the functions have no main method), and the issue you have with output data handling is in code you haven't shown at all.

Comment: Now is better. The main function is from the imported functions. If i run the code in one script, i dont have a problem. So the issue isnt on the main() function, but on how inuse the multiprocessing library

Comment: It's not the multiprocessing library that is saving data. The part that is failing is not among the parts you're showing.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but if you read my question, you could see that I run 4 times exactly the same code. And the first time the output saved without any problem. So, the problem is that somehow, code22,33 and 44 don't run. I could post the other part that you want to see but it is 200 lines of code.

Comment: If it's still the same code then there's no reason to duplicate it into multiple modules - unless they're using globals, in which case you'd still get away with it using multiprocessing. And yes, I think I would like to see the running code. The first guess at what happens is that they all run but overwrite each other's output.

Comment: I understand and as I said, I appreciate it. I don't want to feel that I am against you. I tried to make an example of how my code11,22 etc are. All functions in there works perfect if I run them independently

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42888/discussion-between-yann-vernier-and-anastasios)

Answer (score 1):

This is something more suited to the `multiprocessing.Pool()` class.

Here's a simple example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def job(args):
    """Your job function"""


Pool().map(job, inputs)
```

Where:

- `inputs` is your list of inputs. Each input gets passed to job and processed in a separate process.

You get the results back as a list when all jobs have completed.

`multiprocessing.Pool().map` is just like the Python builtin `map()` but sets up a process pool of workers for you and passes each input to the given function.

See the docs for more details: http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: If I will do this with this way, the output file will be overwritted. I used 4 different functions in order to have 4 different names for the output json files.

Comment: You make your ``job()`` function output the files and write to separate files. The ``job()`` function doesn't have to return anything.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I tried with 3 and 4 pools, but my quadcore laptop freezed in both of the cases. Is that ok and I can user only 2 pools?

Comment: One pool is enough; it starts as many worker processes as you have processors, unless directed otherwise.

Comment: Turns out Python multiprocessing on Windows doesn't fork, but re-imports the main module, leading to some additional constraints: http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows

Comment: Typo: `from mulriprocessing import Pool` mulriprocessing -> multiprocessing